# find work given only force field

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

Usually, the **curve** is given. But not for this problem which states:
a particle of mass m moves under the influence of the force field
$ F = a \sin \omega t i, a \cos \omega t j $
prove that work done up time t is $ a^2 / m \omega^2  (1 - \cos \omega t) $

It looks like a circle. So if $ r =  a \cos \omega t  i, a \sin \omega t j $
And $ dr = (- a \sin \omega t i, a \cos \omega t j) dt $
$work = \int F.dr $
But this line integral does not produce the result. I guess something wrong with
my curve definition.

Update.
With amd's hint the rest is easy. The idea is to compute the velocity at
time t, to get the kinetic energy of the particle, which is equal to
the work done. So first we find the acceleration by $ a = F/m $
Then we integrate acceleration to get the velocity.

Comment: You’re not being asked to compute the work done against the force field when moving the particle in a certain way. You’re by asked to compute the work done *by* the force field as it acts on a particle that experiences no other forces.

Comment: @amd thank you for the clarification. Now I am able to produce the correct answer.